# Button not correctly located with autolayout after updating constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm stuck with a strange bug with Auto Layout.

I have two buttons (confirm and delete) side by side, in the same view, each taking a width that's 50% of their superview, and in some situations (when test = true), I want to hide confirm button so delete button takes all the width of the screen.

Here is my autolayout:

[image]

Confirm button:

[image]

Delete button:

[image]

Proportional width is 50% (1:2) of the superview. Now here is my call, happening in `viewWillAppear`:

```
if test {
    self.confirmButtonWidthConstraint.constant = 0
    self.deleteButtonWidthConstraint.constant = (self.deleteButton.superview?.frame.width)!
}
```

However, after doing so here is the result:

[image]

And after checking the UI debugger, I can see that oddly, this delete button now has a width of... 480, with a starting x of -160. So I don't really know what's happening here. Please help!

[image]

Comment: If your constraints are using data that is determined by Autolayout (such as the width of a view), you should call the relevant code in either `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` depending on the exact use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but still getting the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest a different tactic?

Embed your buttons in a stack view (`UIStackView`) with the buttons set to fill equally.

You can then set your button to disappear with `button.isHidden = true`. The stack view will handle the layout for you gracefully.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You've set the width proportionally but are updating the constraints `constant` property. This will need lead to the result you desire as the proportional width will simply add the `constant` value to the multiplier result.

Instead you should set the `multiplier` property of your constraints. For example:

```
if test {
    self.confirmButtonWidthConstraint.multiplier = 0.0
    self.deleteButtonWidthConstraint.multiplier = 1.0
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, I see now what was my mistake. I ended up using Jack Daw’s solution since it seems more “natural” to me, but it definitely makes sense. Thanks again !

Comment: Yes, his solution is preferred. Glad you got it working. Happy coding!